# How do I get values dynamically from radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

This is an on change event for anything changed on the page.

```
$(this).change(function(){
    type = $('input[name='+$(this).name+'radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val();
    alert(type);
});
```

I want to get the radio button that is clicked. So I can show the hidden input box when Profit is clicked.

```
<TD align=left>
    <input type=radio name="Red" value="l" checked>Loss
    <input type=radio name="Red" value="w">Win
    <input type=radio name="Red" value="p">Profit
    <INPUT value="" name="profitRed" LENGTH="5" hidden>
</TD>
<TD align=left>
    <input type=radio name="Black" value="l" checked>Loss
    <input type=radio name="Black" value="w">Win
    <input type=radio name="Black" value="p">Profit
    <INPUT value="" name="profitBlack" LENGTH="5" hidden>
</TD>
```

So what ever radio button gets clicked, I want to grab the name, and check the value. If the value is "p", then I want to update the corresponding text box.

```
If(type=="p")
{
    $("profit"+$(this).name).show();
}
```

I'm new to JQuery and really hope someone can help me with this. It would make things so much easier than having to check each name.

Thanks a ton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('click',function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
     var name = $(this).attr('name');
     if(value == 'p'){
         // add . for class or # for id
         $('#profit'+ name).show();
         // this will show the element with Id='profitBlack'
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to inputs not $(this). Once there has been a change you can get the name and check if the value equals p.

```
$('input').change(function(){
    type = $(this).attr('name');
    alert(type);
    if($(this).attr('value')=='p')
        $("profit"+$(this).name).show();
});
```

Comment: please add more details explaining your answer